# How I get all elm with attr example font-size: 16px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all elm with some attr and add to them class.
TNX.

```
enter code here
```

> ```
> bla bla bla
> ```

Comment: Not enough data... Where font size is defined? Inline style, or external CSS? font-size is not an valid html attribute, btw (i guess that you talk about inline styles)... Provide example html, desired output, and some code, if any...

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript:

```
var elm = document.querySeletorAll('.class');
for(i = 0; i < elm.length; i++){
    elm[i].className = 'your className';
}
```

jQuery:

```
var elm = $('.class');
for(i = 0; i < elm.length; i++){
    elm[i].attr('class', 'your className'); 
    // OR
    elm[i].addClass('your className');
}
```

Choose what you can work comfortable with